# Extract multiple tar files to their own directory on tar version 1.26

Tags: centos, tar

I am trying to extract multiple tar files by creating a directory of the same name as tar file.
I am using centos with tar version 1.26 and unfortunately can't update the tar version to 1.29 or above due to user restrictions. So am unable to use the below snippet.

```
-exec tar xvf {} --one-top-level \;
```

Trying to replicate the working code I have for.ZIP format but no success.

Working Code for zip file -

```
for file in `ls *.zip`; do unzip $file -d `echo $file | cut -d . -f 1`; done
```

Replicated code for tar files -

```
for f in 'ls *.tar'; do tar xvf $f -C 'echo $f|cut -d . -f 1'; done
```

The code works until I pass "tar xvf $f -C".
This correctly prints the name of files -

```
for f in 'ls *.tar'; do echo $f|cut -d . -f 1; done
```

It gives the below error -

```
$ for f in 'ls *.tar'; do tar xvf $f -C 'echo $f|cut -d . -f 1'; done
```

tar: ls: Cannot open: No such file or directory

tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Thanks,

Pankaj

Comment: Make sure you're using back quotes as in the example and not single quotes.

Comment: I double-checked, am using back quotes

Comment: `for f in *.tar; do tar xvf "$f" -C "${f%.tar}"; done`. See [Bash Pitfall #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this and update.